# How to display app icon badge in React-Native (Expo) app?

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, expo, badge

I'm developing a mobile application using React Native (Expo). I've used `Expo Push Notifications` to handle my notifications. Now I want to display a badge on my app icon which shows the number of new notifications.

Can you please tell me how to do this? I tried using `react-native-shortcut-badge` third-party library. But it gives me an error.

Comment: Are you trying it on iOS or Android device?

Comment: @AlexandreLage On an Android device. For iOS I will be able to use `PushNotificationIOS`. But, I want the same behavior on Android as well.

Comment: Oh nice. Is your app ejected from expo? I mean, do you see `android` and `ios` folders inside your project directory?

Comment: @AlexandreLage No... I didn't eject it yet.. I'm trying to manage this without ejecting..

Comment: Alright. Both Android and iOS supports badge number on app icons. I suppose you'd just need to receive the notifications. Are you already receiving notifications fine? Are you familiar with local notifications (included in Expo Notifications package)?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm using local notifications in Expo notifications and I receive all the notifications very well. What I want is, set the badge number on my app icon when I receive a new notification.

Comment: @AlexandreLage Can you please suggest to me what to do? Please...